# AWS Nodejs process.on 'uncaughtException' not working

Tags: node.js, logging, aws-lambda

I am trying to modify the behavior of process.on uncaughtException, I am logging some extra info with the error. I added sample code below

```
process.removeAllListeners("uncaughtException");

process.on("uncaughtException", (error) => {
  console.log('test message)
  process.exit(1)
});
```

It is not logging 'test message', as you can see I already removedAllListeners, this works for unhandledRejection, but now not uncaughtException

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this working?
Thanks